# How to show the entire labels in Y axis with Google Data Studio?

Tags: dashboard, looker-studio

I am using Google Data Studio to create some horizontal bar charts. When creating these charts, the names in the Y axis don't appear entirely. Instead of showing "Personas que puedan morir", for example, it shows "Person...". This is not understandable. People can read with hover, but the report will be static, not interactive.

How can it show the entire name?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Y-Axis can be moved by hovering the mouse over the Y-Axis, then when the icon changes to a slider, click and drag in the required direction.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/64ee78dd-501e-46e0-8c0e-d534bcb178b1) and GIF to elaborate:

[image]